# TeamCity won't create its schema in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, teamcity

I've installed a new TeamCity instance and just moved from internal storage to database (SQL Server). Followed the instructions at http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Setting+up+an+External+Database and I know I've done the database part correctly as it wouldn't initially connect and I had to go back and turn on TCP/IP connections for SQL Server.

From the documentation I assumed that team city would create and maintain it's own database schema, but even though it's user is dbo the database remains blank - no tables, views or any other objects have been created.

When I try to connect to it in a browser I get "Database is empty or doesn't exist", and viewing the logs shows me "Schema contains no tables". I've obviously restarted the service and connected again each time.

Is there an install script I am missing? How do I get TeamCity to install it's schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing it like this, you will need to migrate the initial structure over to sql server.  [See here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/Migrating+to+an+External+Database)

Comment: As I didn't have any data to migrate it never occurred to me to read that doc. This worked perfectly - thank you.